# Removing duplicates from a string in Python without using adittional buffer

Tags: python, string

I want to resolve this problem in Python:

```
given a string (without spacing), remove the duplicates without using an adittional buffer.
```

I have the following code:

```
 def removedup(st):
 temp = []
 for i in range(len(st)):
         if st[i] not in temp:
                 temp.append(st[i])
 return temp
```

which returns a list without duplicates.

1-This code in O(n^2) right?

2- How I can do the same without using an additional buffer in python?? (I mean not using a list). Maybe I can use a string (not a list) but am not sure if this adds complexity. Also, strings in python are immutable, so I can't do some type of indexing to change something. (Like in C++ or Java).

What is the best way to resolve this in Python? I know that there is some questions that "looks like" duplicates here, but my question is more Python related (solving this without an additional buffer).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) Well

```
return set(st)
```

..is by far the simplest way to uniquify a string (or any iterable).  I don't know if you consider this an "additional buffer" or not.  Some extra memory needs to be allocated for another object any way you do it, since strings are immutable as you say.

This of course does not preserve order, and if that's an issue there's always the super-obvious:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

return ''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(st))
```

Comment: @JonClements oh yeah, guess not.

Comment: Yes, I read about that. The problem with set is just that I am using something built-in (too easy!). How do you convert a set to a string? (It seems trivial but I done know how!) Is there some way to do this without using set, join or a list? if not, my answer is correct, right?

Comment: @Edwardo there are *lots* of ways to do this.  But telling me that the correct methods are "too easy" is not a reason.  Give us actual unambiguous design parameters or there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: Ok sorry. I am trying to practice for a tech interview and I found this problem. Because of that context, I am not sure if using set is a valid thing. I am sorry for the ambiguity, but is my first interview and I don't know if I can use set (for example) to solve this. Lets say then, that I can't use List or sets to solve this. How I can do it? (Again, sorry for the ambiguity)

Comment: @Edwardo if I were asking this as an interview question I would ask the interviewee to defend their answer, whatever it is.  The `set` answer is O(n) in space and time (which is optimal) so as long as they know that it is fine to give the "easy" built-in answer.

Comment: OK, Thank you. So, the answer can be "".join(list(set(x)))? using list and join adds just a consntant in time complexity right? so this is O(n)? I am not so familiar with this ones...

Comment: @Edwardo you can just do `''.join(set(x))`.  No need to fill a list, a `set` is already an iterable that you can pass to `join`.

Comment: ok! thank you. So join is a O(n) opeartion? it does not change the complexity?

Answer (score 1):

0) Apparently you have to use at least one additional buffer since, as you have mentioned, python strings are immutable and you need at least to return result somehow, right? So internaly at least one buffer is already used (even if you name it with the same name).

You can, of course, use string as buffer, they can do string + string or string += string, or even string[:n-1] + string[n:], but because of immutability, internaly it creates new object each time.

You can use some other, mutable, iterable instead of string, so it would work.

1) No, your code is not O(N**2). It's O(N*log(N)) in the worst case scenario (all symbols are unique) and O(N) in best case scenario (all symbols are just one symbol).

2) Assuming that you use list instead of string of string, you could do something like this:

```
def dup_remove(lst):
    i = 0
    n = len(lst)
    while i < n:
        if lst[i] in lst[:i]:
            del lst[i]
            n -= 1
        else:
            i += 1
        return lst
```

it's still O(N*Log(N)) in worst case scenario, but it does not use any additional buffers which is what you wanted in the first place. I think that for practical purpose solution with OrderedDict should be more optimal though.

Comment: Could you explain your O(N log N) argument?  Where is the log N coming from?  The sequence isn't sorted.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why my algorithm is O(N*log(N))? I dont understand why... also I dont understand why are you using del on your code.. each del can be O(n) right? because, you have to me all elements...

Comment: Ok, you go through the original string which length is N, on each step you go through the additional list until found the current symbol. In the worst case scenario you have string with only unique symbols, so:

1) You check the first symbol, additional list is empty: 1 step.
2) You check the second symbol, additional list has one symbol in it: 2 steps.
3) You check the third symbol, additional list has two symbols in it: 3 steps.
....
N) You check N-th symbol, additional list has N-1 symbols in it: N steps.

So we don't have N checking steps for each symbol, only (1+2+3+...N)/N.

Comment: Edwardo, del lst[i] complexity depends on realization of list. For linked list it's O(i) (not O(N), 'cause only i steps are required to get to i-th element from zeroth), and for array it should be O(N-i) since we should move all the elements after i-th. But I'm sure that Python library uses neither one for list, never looked at sources, but there ought to be some sort optimization for quick indexing.

Comment: I don't think your unique-case math is right.  First loop: 1 step.  Second: 2.  Nth: N.  so total steps = 1+2+3...+N = N*(N+1)/2 = O(N^2).  No log Ns anywhere in sight.  As for `del`, as you suspected, Python's `list` type is an array, not a linked list.

Comment: Yeah, of course you're right and I'm wrong. Thanks for correction :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it through list slicing loop.

```
# O(n ^ 2)
for item in input_list[:]:
    index = input_list.index(item) + 1
    while index < len(input_list):
        if input_list[index] == item:
            del input_list[index]
        index += 1
```

Since slice creates a copy, if you truly want a solution without any internal buffers, this will do.

```
# O(n ^ 2)
i = 0
while i < len(input_list):
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(input_list):
        if input_list[j] == input_list[i]:
            del input_list[j]
            # Don't increment j here since the next item
            # after the deleted one will move to index j
        else:
            j += 1
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure.

2) A very efficient way is coded below. Note that I don't use any additional package. I don't even use lists, just a string!

```
def removeDuplicate (input):   

i = 0
while i < len(input)-1:
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(input):
        if input[j] == input[i]:                
            input_list = input_list[0:j] + input_list[j+1:]                
            # Don't increment j here since the next item
            # after the deleted one will move to index j
        else:
            j += 1
    i += 1

return input
```